# How do I return data when the condition of two statements are true?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I'm trying to get a data point to return but only if two statements are true.

Statement one: If Date of cell B32 (Sheet 2) = The Date of B2 (Sheet 1)
Statement two: If Cell Name C30 (Sheet 2) = Cell Name C2 (Sheet 1)
Then C32 (Sheet 2) would display the data point from D2 (Sheet 1)

So if these two conditions are met, then the cell would return the data point I wanted.

Also I'm not sure if I should be using B2/C2 of the whole columns of B/C in my formula. I'd like some input on that as well.

Photo 1: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwIeyMliU7Z4TmZ4N29VbGRrMnc

Photo 2: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwIeyMliU7Z4eS1iRHF4a1QxcTQ

Comment: If you provide some example data, it'll be easier to examine the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. Sample sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lGT7_XC4qIuMzLnbCCFEPZ_vSYkWdYBKMYtdbH67y08/edit#gid=84678636). You should search and study `sumif`, `sumifs`, `countif`, `countifs`, etc. Formula which ends with `s` can handle multiple conditions.

```
=sumifs(report!D:D, report!B:B, "="&$B32, report!C:C, "="&C$30)
```

Though, the structure of your sheets is not scalable.

Comment: Sheet 1 is named Dashboard and Sheet 2 is named Nightly Report Form Responses. Under the tab Dashboard, I have six different districts separated by dates. Each district has the column Not Home. Under the tab Nightly Report Form Responses, I have dates, districts 1-6, and Not Home. 
I want to match the Nightly Report Form Responses tab with the Dashboard. I need the formula to match the date and district, and auto-populate the number of Not Homes from Nightly Report Form Responses to the Dashboard.

Comment: For example, if on 3/5/2017 there were 81 Not Homes in District 6 and 432 Not Homes in District 1 under the Nightly Report Form Responses; I would need the Dashboard to reflect 3/5/2017  Not Home 432 in District 1 and 3/5/2017  Not Home 81.

Comment: @RodWright Please don't explain it in words. Instead please provide it as Google sheet or something.

Comment: Okay, I edited the answer. You should edit your question too, especially please include those photos into your question body.